# Nightwatch Automated UI Script - Browser Not Loading Data

Tags: selenium, automation, database-connection, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I have some UI test scripts running that for some reason don't receive valid JSON responses for certain requests.

When the test steps are executed manaually a valid JSON response is returned.

When the same steps are automated the browser is unable to load and display the same data.

[When running an automated test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwfaY.png)

Any ideas because I can not figure out why this is happening>

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant see your code, I will have to take an educated guess.

Have you considered you are moving too quickly for the element to be visible/present?

Think about using:

`Page.waitForElementPresent('@selectorOfChoice', 'Present: selectorOfChoice');`

or

`Page.waitForElementVisible('@selectorOfChoice', 'Visible: selectorOfChoice');`

a pause can be used too:

`Page.waitForElementVisible('@selectorOfChoice', 15000, 'Visible: selectorOfChoice');`

`Page.api.pause(10000);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply and no it wasn't the case!

It was actually a configuration issue with the website that I'm testing that caused it.